# How to insert an Object into MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So I have an object using a dictionary to store products that a user has added to the cart in a shopping cart application. I am taking is object and attempting to insert into mongoDB with zero luck.

The piece of data I am attempting to insert looks like this:

```
products: '{"rJUg4uiGl":{"productPrice":"78.34","count":2},"BJ_7VOiGg":{"productPrice":"3","count":2}}' }
```

My process of attempting to insert it into mongoDB looks like this:

```
db.orders.insert("products":{"rJUg4uiGl":{"productPrice":"78.34","count":2},"BJ_7VOiGg":{"productPrice":"3","count":2}});
```

Currently with this approach I get the following error:

```
2016-12-15T18:11:43.862-0500 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list @(shell):1:27
```

Which is implying there is some sort of a formatting issue with inserting it. I have moved quotation marks and parenthesis around plenty, simply to either get the above error, or a ... response from mongoDB implying that it is waiting for me to do something more to fix what exactly is causing an error.

Any chance anyone could help give some guidance in the best way to store this object in mongoDB?

**My true question** feels that it should have been in regards to the mongoose schema that would be used in order to store this data format. I hoped that getting how to initially insert it into mongodb was going to be enough but the way the data is being saved has me a bit confused. I know this is a bit of an awful question but could I get any assistance with setting up my schema for this as well?

```
"products" : {
    "rJUg4uiGl" : {
        "productPrice" : "78.34",
        "count" : 2
    },
    "BJ_7VOiGg" : {
        "productPrice" : "3",
        "count" : 2
    }
}
```

This is what the data looks like when it is stored in mongo. I think what is confusing me on how to set up is the "rJUg4uiGl" portion of the data. I am un-sure of how exactly that is suppose to look in mongoose schema. Here are a few of my rather poor attempts:

```
products: {
    productId: {
        productPrice: Number,
        count: Number
    }
}
```

Above simply doesn't store anything in the database

```
products: {
    productId: [{
        productPrice: Number,
        count: Number
    }]
}
```

Above gives:

```
"products" : {
    "productId" : [ ]
}
```

Again, I know that this is quite specific but any help at all would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: `db.orders.insert("products":` You need a `{` after the `(` to start the object.

Comment: Well thats embarrassing.  Thank you, that was exactly the issue. :(

Comment: @Thilo I updated my question a little to get some hopeful guidance on setting this up in a mongoose schema as well. I know this is not the greatest question in general but any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @qxz Any chance you could assist with **My True Question**? Only reaching out because you had helped me set up this data format in the first place. Also, know its not the greatest question but again, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Need to wrap your insert data in {}

db.orders.insert({"products":{"rJUg4uiGl":{"productPrice":"78.34","count":2},"BJ_7VOiGg":{"productPrice":"3","count":2}}});

Comment: Well thats embarrassing :(. Thank you, that was exactly the issue.

Comment: I updated my question a little to get some hopeful guidance on setting this up in a mongoose schema as well. I know this is not the greatest question in general but any help is greatly appreciated. @jmiraglia

Comment: I don't know anything about mongoose but I'd venture a guess that you'd want "products" to be an array of "product" objects. i.e. products: [{productId: Number,  productPrice: Number, productCount: Number},{productId: Number,  productPrice: Number, productCount: Number}]